# How to theme a tableGrob object from gridExtra in r

Tags: r, gridextra, grob

I would like to re-use a theme/template/default for a `tableGrob` object from the `gridExtra` package in `r`.

```
library(gridExtra)

tableGrob(df, cols = c("Custom Name", "Custom Name2"), 
          show.rownames = FALSE, h.even.alpha = 0)

tableGrob(df2, cols = c("Different Name", "Different Name2"), 
          show.rownames = FALSE, h.even.alpha = 0)
```

Notice, I do not want to have to repeat `show.rownames = FALSE` and `h.even.alpha = 0` multiple times. What is the appropriate way to create a theme or template of some type to avoid repeating these options over different calls to `tableGrob`? Can I do this with a theme similar to `ggplot2` or is a function my best bet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a new function that sets the fixed parameters to the values you want and only requires you to provide a data frame and column names:

```
myTG = function(data.frame, cols = c("Name 1", "Name 2")) {
  tableGrob(data.frame, cols = cols, show.rownames = FALSE, h.even.alpha = 0)
}
```

Then to run it:

```
tg1 = myTG(df, c("Custom Name 1", "Custom Name 2"))
```